# Can we auto populate data from one user lookup of object_1__C to object_2__C user look up

Tags: trigger, workflow, lookup, process-builder, process

I have an object 1 with user lookup, Right now I am using formula field to populate user to other object. But i have requirement i need to populate from selected user from user lookup to other user lookup when 2nd object is created.

Object 2 has lookup relationship for object 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pre-populate values in Standard Page Layout then, you need to use Custom button which will override the URL and pass the Id of the Lookup field as a parameter and assign the value from the URL.

For more information, refer this link: [Pre-populate fields in SFDC](http://www.bulkified.com/article/?articleid=18)

Just to tell you it field id varies environment wise. So after deployment, you have change this field Id based on that environment.